# Is there any workaround for EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied:

Tags: python, jupyter-lab

Getting below error when trying to upgrade jupyter lab using pip. Have tried `pip3 install --user jupyter lab --upgrade` but still not working

`ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: C:\\Users\\ADITHYA\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-uninstall-low949lo\\jupyter.exe`

`Consider using the` --user `option or check the permissions.`

Answer (score -1):

Right click and check user privileges of the folder `C:\Users\ADITHYA\` and open up write permissions for your account now.

If this fails, find `cmd.exe` in `C:\Windows\System32\` and right click on it, then "run as administrator" - now you can execute any command in it without worrying permission.